# How to create a Solution from single .cs file with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to create a Solution from a single source file and tested different solutions.
One of them is the following:

```
       var info = ProjectInfo.Create(
            projectId,
            version: VersionStamp.Default,
            name: "TestProject",
            assemblyName: "TestProject.dll",
            language: LanguageNames.CSharp);

        using (var ws = new CustomWorkspace())
        {
            var project = ws.AddProject(info);
        }
```

But when running this code, I just get an exception saying that "language is not supported".

Any hint about what is happening?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.CSharp.dll is copied alongside your project. We detect that it's there and load it to provide C# support.